# Rows inside the greatest streak?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, gaps-and-islands

Given the Rows

```
symbol_id profit date
1         100    2009-08-18 01:01:00
1         100    2009-08-18 01:01:01
1         156    2009-08-18 01:01:04
1         -56    2009-08-18 01:01:06
1         18     2009-08-18 01:01:07
```

How would I most efficiently select the rows that are involved in the greatest streak (of profit).

The greatest streak would be the first 3 rows, and I would want those rows.  The query I came up with is just a bunch of nested queries and derived tables.  I am looking for an efficient way to do this using common table expressions or something more advanced.

Comment: What defines `the greatest streak`?  Sequence ending in highest profit, starting immediately after a negative profit?

Comment: Yes, profit is a streak, negative profit ends streak

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't defined how `0` profit should be treated or what happens if there is a tie for longest streak. But something like...

```
;WITH T1 AS
(
SELECT *,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY symbol_id ORDER BY date) - 
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY symbol_id, SIGN(profit) 
                              ORDER BY date) AS Grp 
FROM  Data      
), T2 AS  
(
SELECT *,
       COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY symbol_id,Grp) AS StreakLen
FROM T1       
)
SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES *
FROM T2 
ORDER BY  StreakLen DESC
```

Or - if you are looking for most profitable streak

```
;WITH T1 AS
(
SELECT *,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY symbol_id ORDER BY date) - 
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY symbol_id, CASE WHEN profit >= 0 THEN 1 END
                              ORDER BY date) AS Grp 
FROM  Data      
), T2 AS  
(
SELECT *,
       SUM(profit) OVER (PARTITION BY symbol_id,Grp) AS StreakProfit
FROM T1       
)
SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES *
FROM T2 
ORDER BY  StreakProfit DESC
```

Comment: Will be interesting if the sequence `1,2,3,4,5,4,3,4,5,6` should yield `3,4,5,6` as the streak.

Comment: WOW.  11,618,019 rows in my table and the query executes instantly.  You're a life saver.  Now, I'm going to have to study this query and learn from it.

Answer (score 1):

```
declare @T table
(
  symbol_id int,
  profit int,
  [date] datetime
)

insert into @T values
(1,         100,    '2009-08-18 01:01:00'),
(1,         100,    '2009-08-18 01:01:01'),
(1,         156,    '2009-08-18 01:01:04'),
(1,         -56,    '2009-08-18 01:01:06'),
(1,         18 ,    '2009-08-18 01:01:07')

;with C1 as
(
  select *,
         row_number() over(order by [date]) as rn
  from @T
),
C2 as
(
  select *,
         rn - row_number() over(order by rn) as grp
  from C1
  where profit >= 0
)
select top 1 with ties *
from C2
order by sum(profit) over(partition by grp) desc
```

Result:

```
symbol_id   profit      date                    rn                   grp
----------- ----------- ----------------------- -------------------- --------------------
1           100         2009-08-18 01:01:00.000 1                    0
1           100         2009-08-18 01:01:01.000 2                    0
1           156         2009-08-18 01:01:04.000 3                    0
```

Answer (score 0):

If that's a MSSQL server then you want to consider using TOP 3 in your select clause 
and ORDER BY PROFIT DESC. 
If mysql/postgres you might want to consider using limit in your select clause with 
the same order by too.

hope this helps.

Comment: What if there is another record, at unrelated point in time, with profit of 140?  The sequence needs to be established in datetime order, not profit order...